# Displaying field specific validation error messages in jqGrid (server-side validation)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.5.4 for data editing. The user input is validated on the server. When there are validation errors, the server returns a JSON object which contains field-name/error-message pairs.

I know how to display these messages at the top of the form with the `errorTextFormat` callback, but I'd like to show validation messages near fields that caused them, i.e. I want to achieve something similar to the following:

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use jQuery to manipulate the HTML of the jqGrid form.

**jqGrid settings**

The `Edit` dialogue options: `{errorTextFormat:errorTextFormatF, onclickPgButtons:cleanEditForm, recreateForm:true, ...}`

The `Add` dialogue options: `{errorTextFormat:errorTextFormatF, recreateForm:true}`

jqGrid calls the `errorTextFormat` callback to create an error message that is displayed at the top of the form when an error occurs. The callback returns the error message. Additionally, I used this callback to highlight erroneous fields in the
form.

The `onclickPgButtons` callback is called when the user clicks a navigation button (the left and right arrows).
This callback is used to clear field highlighting when the user moves to the next/previous record.

The `recreateForm:true` is used to make sure that field highlighting disappears when you close the form.

**JavaScript**

```
function errorTextFormatF(data) {

    // The JSON object that comes from the server contains an array of strings:
    // odd elements are field names, and even elements are error messages.
    // If your JSON has a different format, the code should be adjusted accordingly.

    var validationErrors = data.responseJSON.validationErrors;

    if(validationErrors != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < validationErrors.length; i += 2) {
            var selector = ".DataTD #" + validationErrors[i];
            $(selector).after( "<img title='" + validationErrors[i+1] + "' class='jqgrid-error-icon' src='resources/img/emblem-important-2.png'></img>" );
        }
    }

    return "There are some errors in the entered data. Hover over the error icons for details.";
}

function cleanEditForm() {
    $(".jqgrid-error-icon").remove();
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]